# How to memo a function in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am making an application using react and typescript and here I need to memoize a function.

```
  const formatData = (
    data: number[],
    gradientFill?: CanvasGradient
  ): Chart.ChartData => ({
    labels: ["a", "b", "c"],
    datasets: [
      {
        data
      }
    ]
  });
```

I have tried to memo the above function like,

```
  const formatData = useMemo((
    data: number[],
    gradientFill?: CanvasGradient
  ): Chart.ChartData => ({
    labels: ["a", "b", "c"],
    datasets: [
      {
        data
      }
    ]
  }),[]);
```

And this results in the following error.

> Argument of type '(data: number[], gradientFill?: CanvasGradient |
> undefined) => Chart.ChartData' is not assignable to parameter of type
> '() => ChartData'.

Could you please help to properly implement `useMemo` to the above function? Thanks in advance.

**Working example:** (App.tsx file line no 10)

[image: Edit Chart.js React Typescript (forked)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useMemo`'s callback should not take arguments. Arguments should exist in the value *returned* from `useMemo` - the resulting `formatData` function.

```
const formatData = useMemo(() => (
    data: number[],
    gradientFill?: CanvasGradient
): Chart.ChartData => ({
    labels: ["a", "b", "c"],
    datasets: [
        {
            data
        }
    ]
}), []);
```

But `useCallback` would be more appropriate here.

```
const formatData = useCallback((
    data: number[],
    gradientFill?: CanvasGradient
): Chart.ChartData => ({
    labels: ["a", "b", "c"],
    datasets: [
        {
            data
        }
    ]
}), []);
```

Comment: I have already tried ```useCallback``` but my team lead asked to memo the function instead of callback.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of situation `useCallback` was created for - to memoize a callback. While you *can* use `useMemo` to accomplish the same thing, it's odd (confusing - as evidenced by your question - `useCallback` doesn't have the same argument issue) and unnecessarily more verbose. `useCallback` is appropriate for all functions. `useMemo` is appropriate for everything else to be memoized that isn't a function.

Comment: Understood, Does the same statement apply for the another function ```canvasCallback``` as well? (Please take a look at the example in given question and there you can find it)

Comment: Yes, though since the inside of the `canvasCallback` depends on `chartData`, you'll want to add that to the dependency array when you memoize it with `useCallback`: `useCallback(canvas: ....) => { ... }, [chartData])` Could be important just in case the props change

Comment: Okay understood and learned important things from your statement, thanks much bro.